# Change hover / tooltip text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the values of blankSpace and hoverHint using JavaScript, but changing blankSpace completely deletes the HTML for hoverHint... understandably. Is there any way I can get around this and just edit the text value for each of these?

```
<div class="tooltip" id="blankSpace">Hover over me
 <span class="tooltiptext" id="hoverHint">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
document.getElementById("blankSpace").textContent = "___";
document.getElementById("hoverHint").textContent = hintText;
```

Comment: Could you please add the JavaScript code you are using to the question

Comment: @reymon359 Just added, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `childNodes` to access the text node and replace the value in there:

```
document.querySelector('#blankSpace').childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'new text';
```

`document.querySelector('#blankSpace')` will select the div. The first `childNode` will be your text node which you can edit by assigning a new value to its `nodeValue`